# Create a condition to allow only one parameter

Tags: javascript, object

I am beginner in javascript and I will just like a help to understand the kind of algorithm that I have to do.

Create a condition to allow only one parameter in the aria-errormessage in a object

```js
var ariastatesproperties = {
 'aria-errormessage': { type: ['relationship', 'widget'], global: true }, // id reference
```

```html
<div role="textbox" aria-errormessage="error1 error2" aria-label="A textbox with an error"></div>
```

Comment: What do you mean with parameter (a term mostly used in the context of functions)?

Comment: I do not use the right term but I want to create a condition if someone create a html tag with an aria-errormessage with more than two words, there is an error message.
because errormessage can only contain one parameter according to rgaa4, this is accessibility

Comment: So, if I understand correctly you want to validate that the *attribute value* for `aria-errormessage` does not contain a space. And you want to do this validation with JavaScript. What should happen when it is found to be invalid?

Comment: Also, what do you mean with *"if someone create a html tag"*. Do you have a user-interface that allows users to create HTML tags? Or do you mean that if someone includes your JavaScript library into their own HTML page, the document's elements should all be validated?

Comment: It's almost that. The aria-errormessage should contain only one value. If there is a space or more than one value, there is an error message that indicates that errormessage should contain only one value.

Comment: An error message about an error message sounds circular. Could you be explicit in *what* you expect to happen? Should there be an `alert`, or do you have a function that returns a boolean for that purpose? What about my other question?

Comment: all elements that meet the conditions must be validated.

And yes I try to create an extension that validates or invalidates the elements of access not respected. For now only a alert or console.log will be great. The most important it's the function conditional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scan the document with this loop:

```
for (let elem of document.querySelectorAll("[aria-errormessage]")) {
    if (elem.getAttribute("aria-errormessage").includes(" ")) {
        console.log("invalid: ", elem.outerHTML);
    }
}
```

If you want to use `filter`, then turn the nodelist into an array first:

```
let invalidElems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("[aria-errormessage]"))
          .filter(elem => elem.getAttribute("aria-errormessage").includes(" "));
```

If spaces at the very start or end of the attribute value are acceptable, then first trim the value before checking for a space:

```
elem.getAttribute("aria-errormessage").trim().includes(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just get the checked element. Then check the "aria-errormessage" attribute. If it contains more than one word, it will be an error.

```
var div = document.getElementById('div-id');
if (div["aria-errormessage"].split(" ").length > 1) {
    return "error";
} else {
    return "ok";
}
```

Comment: can i replace split with filter ?

Comment: Not in this case, div["aria-errormessage"] returns a string not an array.